# How to differentiate between the sortable update events when dragging within the same list and when moving from one list to a connected list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connected sortable lists, `#origin` and `#destination`. When you drag and drop from `#origin` to `#destination`, I can see that the following events occur in this order:

1. `#origin` update
2. `#origin` remove
3. `#destination` receive
4. `#destination` update

However when dragging and dropping within the `#origin` list, only the `#origin` update function is executed.

The problem is that when `#origin` update is executed it looks exactly the same as when dragging and dropping within the same list. In both cases, `ui.sender` is not set and since it is executed *before* the remove function is executed, I have no way of setting a temporary variable to say what is happening.

(see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr9d2/1/) and look at the console)

I want to include an ajax call in my update function without it being executed twice. I therefore need a way to differentiate between the `#origin` update called when dragging from one list to another (so I can basically just `return false`) and when dragging within the same list.

I thought of getting the `ui.position` and checking to see if that coordinate is within the boundaries of `#origin`, but it seems like there has to be a more simple solution.

Comment: From the order I see in the console, is there a way to detect if "remove" has been fired? It seems like "remove" is never fired when dragging within the same list...

Comment: @Bonatoc That's because nothing is removed.

Comment: Sorry, a comment in your JSFiddle says "// The following three are executed in this order" with "remove" being the first. Why don't you assume that in absence of "remove" execution, item must have been dropped within the same area? Not very state-of-the-art, I'll give you that...

Comment: @Bonatoc I apologize, the comment was wrong. That's the order I *thought* they were in initially, but I didn't realize that `update` was being executed twice and I forgot to change the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way you could do it:
Set a flag for each group, origin and destination. Initialize it above the `sortable` like this:

```
var updates={origin:false,destination:false};
$( ".config-room-ul" ).sortable({//...
```

in the update method, add this to the top

```
update: function(e, ui) {
updates[$(this).attr('id')]=true; //...
```

now add a handler for the `stop` event which is fired at the end:

```
stop:function (e,ui) {
            if (updates.origin===true && updates.destination===true)
            {
             console.log('dragged from one group to another group');   
            }
            else if(updates.origin===true && updates.destination===false)
            {
             console.log('dragged within origin');   
            }
            else if(updates.origin===false && updates.destination===true)
            {
                console.log('dragged within destination');
            }

            //finally, clear out the updates object
            updates.origin=false;
            updates.destination=false;
        }
```

now the console should show "dragged within origin" or "dragged within destination" if something is dragged inside its own group. it should show "dragged from one group to another group" if you drag to another group.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wr9d2/3/

PS If you need to determine from which group the drag started and ended when dragging between groups, I think the code is easily editable to do that.

Comment: That's a much cleaner way to do it than my answer. I'm accepting this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I thought of instead of using the position is to count the number of child elements of the `#origin` list before and after the drag and comparing them. If they are different then the `update` function called is from the `#origin`. You also need to compare the element ID to make sure they match.

First add this before your `sortable` declaration:

```
var sender_id = null;
var sender_children = 0;
```

Then add the following drag start option:

```
    start: function(e, ui) {
        sender_id = $(this).attr("id");
        // Get number of child elements from the sender. We subtract 1
        // because of the placeholder (which adds another child)
        sender_children = $(this).children().length - 1;
    }
```

Then in the `update` function, check if the sender's id matches, `ui.sender` is null and the number of children for the sender element are different. It should be one less because the element you dragged has been removed. If it is, then skip that one because it is being called from the origin and not the destination.

```
    if ($(this).attr("id") == sender_id
        && ui.sender == null
        && $(this).children().length != sender_children
    ) {
        return true;
    }
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr9d2/2/).